Hotspot speed capped. Need urgent help
I am a new Linux user. I have recently install Ubuntu because I wanted to try stable distros after staying on arch Linux for a long time. I had this same issue in all Linux distros and now it has started to bother me a lot. I use personal hotspot from my phone to my laptop a lot. Whenever I use my personal hotspot from my phone, the internet speed is capped at 3MB/s. Why?! I need fast internet! This is the biggest issue I have faced till now. Can someone help?
My wifi card is azurewave and it has Qualcomm qca9377 chip and uses ath10k

Welcome to AskUbuntu. Silly question, but are you sure the problem is with Ubuntu? Does your internet provider have a transmission speed limit in place? Do they use aggressive QoS scheduling to reduce the priority of Linux-based traffic?

Idk. I have a sim card in my phone from which I take the internet. This is a distro universal issue. This doesn't occur when connected to a router or if I connect my phone with a wire.
